# CSS Selector equivalent of XPath

Tags: css, selenium

What is the CSS selector equivalent of XPath "//a[contains(text(),'Next »')]"?

Thanks

Comment: You can't select elements by their values. There are other ways in CSS to achieve this, using classes and other attributes.

Comment: Try this, `a:contains('Next »')`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot find text with CSS directly, you could set CSS properties via JavaScript based on the internal contents but in the end you would still need to be operating in the definitions of CSS.